# How do I move my textView when tapped so the keyboard does not hide it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2

I am trying to move my UITextView to the upper half of the screen when the user taps it to begin editing. Then, when the user is done, the UITextView will return to the original position. When I run the code and tap the `UITextView`, the it moves to the new position but then immediately returns. What am I not doing to get the `UITextField` to remain in the new position until the user is finished editing? I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and Swift2. Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textViewField: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textViewField.layer.cornerRadius = 10

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { () -> Void in
    self.textViewField.center = CGPointMake(self.textViewField.center.x, self.textViewField.center.y + 400)}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If you are then you can't directly edit the frame of your textfield, you need to edit the constraints on it to shift it up.

Comment: @dan Thank you for your reply. I am using auto layout. Can you point me in the right direction for how to edit the constraints? Can I code the location and size of the `UITextView`? If so, how. This is my first project and I am quite new to coding.

Comment: Here's a decent looking tutorial that should be similar enough to your situation that you can adapt it: http://effortlesscode.com/auto-layout-keyboard-shown-hidden/

Comment: @dan Thank you. That looks like exactly what I need. I have read it over and I think I understand it. I set up my text project with constraints based on the tutorial's example.  I entered the code from the example project but I am getting an error I do not understand. `UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: .BeginFromCurrentState | animationCurve, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)` and the error says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" relating to `BeginFromCurrentState`